Handling XML default namespace in Python using Pydantic
I am trying to convert some JSON data into XML in Python using the Pydantic-XML library (https://pydantic-xml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). However, I am having trouble getting the default namespaces according to my business requirements.
This is my code:
class Socials(
    BaseXmlModel,
    tag='socials',
    nsmap={'': 'http://www.company.com/soc'},
):
    urls: List[str] = element(tag='social')


class Contacts(
    BaseXmlModel,
    tag='contacts',
    nsmap={'': 'http://www.company.com/cnt'},
):
    socials: Socials = element()


class Company(
    BaseXmlModel,
    tag='company',
    nsmap={'': 'http://www.company.com/co'},
):
    contacts: Contacts = element()

My desired output: (requirement from business, ns starts from 1 not 0)
<ns1:company xmlns:ns1="http://www.company.com/co"
             xmlns:ns2="http://www.company.com/cnt"
             xmlns:ns3="http://www.company.com/soc">
    <ns2:contacts>
        <ns3:socials>
            <ns3:social>https://www.linkedin.com/company/spacex</ns2:social>
            <ns3:social>https://twitter.com/spacex</ns2:social>
            <ns3:social>https://www.youtube.com/spacex</ns2:social>
        </ns3:socials>
    </ns2:contacts>
</ns1:company>

What I get from library:
<company xmlns="http://www.company.com/co">
    <contacts xmlns="http://www.company.com/cnt" >
        <socials xmlns="http://www.company.com/soc">
            <social>https://www.linkedin.com/company/spacex</social>
            <social>https://twitter.com/spacex</social>
            <social>https://www.youtube.com/spacex</social>
        </socials>
    </contacts>
</company>

Can anyone help let me know how to achieve this with the pydantic-xml library or any other python library?
Regards,
Krish

I don't know that library but why do you set nsmap={'': 'http://www.company.com/soc'} if you want a prefix of e.g. nsmap={'ns1': 'http://www.company.com/soc'}?

pydantic-xml uses standard XML and the lxml libraries. If a prefix is not given for namespaces, "ns%d" is used as the default namespace.

Also, as for other libraries, I don't understand what the sample JSON data is, the question doesn't show any JSON and part of the content/data in both XML samples, like https://www.linkedin.com/company/spacex doesn't appear anywhere in the Python code. So that problem seems underspecified, at least in general terms, perhaps a user of pydantic knows how to fill in the blanks.

@dskr wondering if you ever solved this
